# How to set colors in a pie chart using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I've used a macro to create a basic script to generate a pie chart in Google sheets.  The pie chart and all characteristics seem to work fine, with the exception of the color of the series (slices).  When I open the script and enter a new color, it keeps defaulting to RED and BLUE, despite other items like width, height, legend location all working properly.  I assume its a basic syntax issue, or perhaps a problem with chaining, or the sequence……?  I am a novice with coding and only use it to extend functionality with my business using web based spreadsheets.  Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide!

Basically I've tried changing the colors to a variety of different options and the color consistently stays blue and red.  When I modify height and width the script runs correctly.

```
function addPieChart() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('d2cStaging');
  var dashboard = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');

  var totalChartLabels = sheet1.getRange("R5:R7");
  var totalChartValues = sheet1.getRange("T5:T7");

  var totalsChart = sheet1.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
  .addRange(totalChartLabels)
  .addRange(totalChartValues)
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setPosition(6,7,0,0)

  .setOption('series.0.color', 'GREEN')
  .setOption('series.1.color', 'YELLOW')

  .setOption('legend.position', 'bottom')
  .setOption('pieSliceText', 'value-and-percentage')
  .setOption('width', 300)
  .setOption('height', 300)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .build();

  dashboard.insertChart(totalsChart);

}
```

I want to be able to change series.0.color to 'PURPLE' and series.1.color to 'ORANGE' and when I re-run the script these results reflect in the displayed chart.

Comment: did you trying using the hexidecimal color values of the colors that you want?

Answer (score 2):

ross's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56549838/9511678) stopped working for me at some point.

This works now:

```
charts.forEach((chart) => {
    chart = chart.modify()
        .asPieChart()
        .setColors(headerColors)
        .build();
    sheet.updateChart(chart);
});
```

The main part being `.asPieChart().setColors(colors)`
as replacement for `.setOption('colors', colors)`

Answer (score 1):

#### Requirement:

Set series colours of chart built with script.

---

#### Solution:

Use the EmbeddedChartBuilder `.setOption()` option "colors".

---

#### Example:

```
.setOption('colors', ['red','blue','#ff0000'])
```

---

#### Explanation:

You can use this to set colors using string values or hexadecimals, the order you place them in will be the order it uses in your series, so series 0 would be the first color in your array of colors in the `setOption`.

You can see the documentation for all of the options available with [Class EmbeddedChartBuilder here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#configuration-options).

Comment: This answer is correct according to the documentation, but it does not work when I implement it.  However, using option `'slices'` instead of `'colors'` accomplishes the desired goal: `.setOption('slices', ['red','blue','#ff0000'])`

Answer (score 0):

ross's answer works, the point is that you must write this command `.setOption('colors', ['red','blue','#ff0000']` at right position in the code, before create the slices.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31171756)